# Google Sheets AppScript Export Cell to HTML file with dynamic folder name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have an app script that exports the contents of a cell into a HTML file in google sheets below:

```
function saveToTextfile() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
var rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 2);
var vs = rg.getValues();
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1rTOhLtYzFAtPH-NuO-uu7OXYH4Ri6vFK')
var files = folder.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
vs.forEach(r => folder.createFile(r[0] + '.html', r[1]) );
```

}

This works perfectly, however, I was wanting to add in another step to export the file to a folder name which would also be based on a cell value.  So for example, instead of simply exporting the files "Index-1.html", "Index-2.html" etc, I want to export this way "/1/index.html", "/2/index.html".  I hope that is clear.

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create subfolders as 1 , 2 and save index.html inside each subfolder ?

Comment: Please consider clarifying whether these are already existing folders (`1`, `2`, etc.) or you want to create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function saveToTextfile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 2);
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => DriveApp.getFolderById(getChildId('1rTOhLtYzFAtPH-NuO-uu7OXYH4Ri6vFK', r[0])).createFile('index.html', r[1]));
}
function getChildId(parentId, name) {
  var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentId);
  var id;
  var folders = parent.getFoldersByName(name);
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    id = folder.getId();
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      if (file.getName() == 'index.html') { file.setTrashed(true) }
    }
  }
  else {
    var folder = parent.createFolder(name);
    id = folder.getId();
  }
  return id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this is perfect!!  

Do you also happen to know if there is a way that when I generate the files, the folder and its contents are not completely deleted?  Say if I had a .png file saved into that folder, when I generate the index.html script, it will delete the entire folder and contents.  Is there a way I can only delete/replace the index.html file?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer to replace only the index.html file.